# Effect on child node animation (rotate,scale and translate) on parent node pivot point

Tags: svg

Hi I'm animating the child node in a dom tree.I want to know the the effect on its parent node pivot point.

Suppose parent node has pivot point px and py .
So what are effects on px and py when

1. child node translated to tx and ty distance .
2. child node scaled by sx and sy in x-y direction with its pivot point cx and cy .
3. child node scaled by changing cx to cx' and cy to cy' and then rotated by an angle alpha.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're thinking of when you say pivot point. If you rotate something using a rotate transform, it rotates about the origin by default unless you explicitly supply a point of rotation

`transform="rotate(angle, cx, cy)"`

where cx and cy are optional

If you change a child element then the parent will stil rotate about the origin or the explicit point you set it to rotate about.

Comment: I'm saying pivot a pt about which scaling is been done .Suppose you've scaled child node with respect to its pivot cx and cy . This causes change in px and py also, you can verify this as after performing scaling on child if you try to scale parent with respect to px and py you will get different behavior as it was before scaling child node.

Comment: I think you would get a better answer if you supplied an example

Comment: I've solved this problem . If we translate child node by tx and ty , the pivot point moves by tx and ty from its last position.